# JQ Grid Compilation Error

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I am new to JQGrid.I downloaded Jqgrid and added the dll in the project.I added a sql data source.but it is showing an error.

**Error**: 'Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridColumn.SearchDataType' is obsolete: 'SearchDataType is now obsolete. Use DataType instead. At runtime set as JQGridColumn.DataType = typeof(string).'

The code after adding sql datasource is

```
 <cc1:JQGrid ID="JQGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="studentid" PrimaryKey="True" 
                SearchDataType="NotSet">
            </cc1:JQGridColumn>
            <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="studentname" SearchDataType="NotSet">
            </cc1:JQGridColumn>
            <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="schoolname" SearchDataType="NotSet">
            </cc1:JQGridColumn>
        </Columns>
    </cc1:JQGrid>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EffortConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [studentid], [studentname], [schoolname] FROM [testjqgrid]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Please help me???